# React-Native Create Read Update and Delete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I just newbie in React Native. I need tutorial about CRUD in react native using API or Firebase. Can you show me a tutorial or give me a link on github maybe.

Comment: Why not use Google first? Have a look [here](https://github.com/griffinsockwell/react-firebase-crud)

Comment: Thanks about your suggest sir. i would try

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can check these two links :

1) for CRUD in react native using API :
https://github.com/code-for-coffee/react-native-crud

2) for CRUD in react native using firebase : https://github.com/earthchie/Firebase-CRUD-Example

i hope that answer your question.

Comment: thank you sir. but i don't find the source code for CRUD using API. where is it?

Answer (score -1):

Check [github repo](https://github.com/hitenluck/firebaseDamo) to get an example of FCM + MAP + FCM Push Notification for a react-native app. An android app is available live on Play Store.

Comment: Thanks sir, but i don't really understand about your app. My knowledge is not enough to understand your app.